# Finding image of a set under bilinear transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $T(z)=i\frac{z+1}{z-1}$, and $A=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:|z|>1\}\cup\{\infty\}$.

How does one find $T(A)$? I tried finding $T^{-1}(z)$, because if $w$ is a point in $T(A)$, then $T^{-1}(w)\in A$. I cannot get anything decent from this, but honestly I don't know if I'm proceeding correctly.

$T^{-1}(z)=\frac{z+i}{z-i}$, so if $T^{-1}(w)\in A$, we have $\left|\frac{w+i}{w-i}\right|>1$... but I can't get anywhere decent from this.

Here are some calculations: let $w=x+iy$,

$$\left|\frac{w+i}{w-i}\right|>1 \Leftrightarrow \left|\frac{(w+i)(\bar{w}+i)}{(w-i)(\bar{w}+i)}\right|>1 \Leftrightarrow \left|\frac{x^2+y^2-1+2ix}{x^2+y^2-2y+1}\right|>1$$

which eventually leads me to the inequality $y(x^2+(y-1)^2)>0$, which doesn't seem to be a reasonable answer for this kind of problem.

Comment: Wait... does this mean $T(A)=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\text{Im}(z)>0, z\neq i\}$?

Answer (score 1):

It takes $\mid z\mid=1$ to the line through $1$ and $0$.  That is, the $x$-axis.

To check which half-plane,  use a test point.  $0\to -i$.  $\therefore $ it's the upper half-plane.

Comment: So, it is always sufficient to just check where $T$ sends the boundary of $A$ to and a single point in $A$ if we're dealing with bilinear transformations?

Comment: For a Möbius transformation this strategy will work.  They take generalized circles to generalized circles.   Notice $1\to\infty$.